# Where is the perfect reference of adobe illustrator script?

Tags: javascript, reference, adobe-illustrator

I'm developing Illustrator Script in Javascript(truly in TypeScript).
And I already know [official Illustrator Scripting reference](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html).
But there are no documents for those methods.

```
// app is an instance of Application class
app.loadAction(f: File)
app.doScript(s: string, s: string)
app.executeMenuCommand(s: string)
...
```

Where is the reference which contains those methods?

Comment: Try [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/illustrator/pdf/Illustrator_JavaScript_Scripting_Reference_2017.pdf#page=8) or [here](http://jongware.mit.edu/iljscs6html/iljscs6/pc_Application.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers you seek are here!

https://forums.adobe.com/message/6114502#6114502

https://forums.adobe.com/message/9323811#9323811

In short, the Adobe scripting forum is your best reference for the more specific questions like this one. You may have learned the hard way from the downvotes this question was besieged with, but they know not what they do; they aren't in a position to truly ever understand you pains.. The Adobe scripting forums though, let me just say 'we have some sights to show you'.

Comment: Also this https://github.com/ten-A/AiMenuObject - this holds a list of executeMenuCommand strings and wraps them in a nicer object syntax

Answer (score 1):

**loadAction**

Load an action into action palette.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Parameter       |   Type   |  Description                                              |
|------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------|
|  actionFilePath  |   File   |  The path on the system of the action file to be loaded.  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**doScript**

Play an action from the Actions Palette.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Parameter    |  Type    |  Description                                                      |
|---------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  action       |  string  |  The name of the action to play*                                  |
|---------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  from         |  string  |  The name of the action set containing the action being played**  |
|---------------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  dialogs      |  bool    |  Are dialog boxes associated with the action to be presented?     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`*note that the case of letters in the Action name is important and must match the case of the name in the Actions palette`

`**note that the case of letters in the Action Set name is important and must match the case of the name in the Actions palette`

---

**executeMenuCommand**

Executes a menu command using the menu shortcut string.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  Parameter          |   Type     |  Description             |
|---------------------+------------+--------------------------|
|  menuCommandString  |   string   |  Menu command shortcut.  |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very relevant... Illustrator docs don't mention the list of commands you're looking for.

I found this open-source list of commands on GitHub: https://github.com/ten-A/AiMenuObject/blob/master/AiMenu_v23.jsxinc

Then the question is: where did its author get the list of names from?