# This script wont select elements/layers which thier names are between angle-brackets "<>"

Tags: reactjs, plugins, adobe-illustrator

Whenever I open a `PDF-file` in `Illustrator` for edithing, there are a lot of ungrouped and uncategorized Elemetns in it.
So I tried to select multiple elements with a spicific name with the below `Script`, but since the name of the elements are between `Angle-brackets` **"`<someName>`"** `script` wont select them:

```
function selectPageItemsByName(items, name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (item.name === name) {
            item.selected = true;
        }
    }
}

function main() {
    var document = app.activeDocument;
    var name = '<someFile>';
    document.selection = null;
    selectPageItemsByName(document.pageItems, name);
}
main();
```

**Femkeblanko from Adobe Community says:** Items with angle brackets in their label (unless user-created) are unnamed.  They correspond to an empty string, i.e. "".

If I remove the `Brackets` from the name of the Elemetns, the `script` works but I have a lot of Elements and it needs time.
So, isn't there a way to salve it?

Comment: you need *something* to select by. a name isn't gonna work as they don't have names. do they have anything in common? what elements are you trying to select? will giving them names help?

Comment: @Yarin_007 They are all Masks which I want to remove.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35057879/how-to-select-and-delete-every-clipping-masks-in-an-illustrator-document-using-j/40981685#40981685)?

Comment: @Yarin_007 you can write it as an answer if you want, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40981685/4935162) is a pretty creative way:

```
// Select->Objects->Clipping Mask
app.executeMenuCommand("Clipping Masks menu item"); 
// Edit->Clear
app.executeMenuCommand("clear");
```

but it isn't really documented very well

some links for future reference:

[Where is the perfect reference of adobe illustrator script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204043/where-is-the-perfect-reference-of-adobe-illustrator-script)

https://ai-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/index.html

https://ten-artai.com/illustrator-ccver-22-menu-commands-list/

https://github.com/ten-A/AiMenuObject